# Typescript export methods on ArrayConstructor

Tags: typescript

How can I export static methods on primitive constructors such as ArrayConstructor, ObjectConstructor, FunctionConstructor, etc?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish: [Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20global%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20interface%20ArrayConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20test()%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0AArray.test%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20true%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20ClassTest%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20func()%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20%7B%20ClassTest%2C%20Array.test%20%7D%3B)

The resulting JS has to still contain Array.test and both function within a Node.js and browser environent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot export *non local definitions*. You can export the `test` function by giving it a local name e.g.:

```
declare global {
    interface ArrayConstructor {
        test(): boolean;
    }
}

const test = Array.test = function () {
    return true;
};

class ClassTest{
    public func() { }
}

export { ClassTest, test };
```

## Ideally

I don't think you want to export the test function. What you probably want to do is:

```
declare global {
    interface ArrayConstructor {
        test(): boolean;
    }
}

Array.test = function () {
    return true;
};

export { }
```

And then when you import this file `Array.test` will magically become available globally.

Comment: The problem with the second choice is that ClassTest is no longer exported. I suppose I could pull that out into it's own file and export it separately. Would you think that is my best option?

Comment: I would not mix *global mutations* with modules. So yeah, `ClassTest` in a non global changing file